# Angular JS Select option from database not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a select option list in Angular.js. I populate list from sql server database. It's working fine. But when I want to display data back from sql server, it doesn't work.

to populate from database (its populated)

```
<select ng-model="roomno" ng-options="r.Room_Name for r in rooms"  value= "{{roomno}}"></select>
```

Now I want to show 1 particular item in that list, which is stored in database.

I tried with

```
$scope.roomno = response.data[0].Room_Name;
```

It's not working.

Comment: You don't need to set the value attribute. Also your model is definitely the string value and not the full object? If it is the object you need to prefill your model with that object for it to select.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest You to use code like this:

```
$scope.roomno = response.data[0].Room_Name.toString();
```

this works fine. because somewhere stores as integer and somewhere string so need to convert as string.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to the server? Presumably you are using HTTP get? In which case if you want one particular room then you might want to call a separate request using the id?:

```
        var _getRoom = function (roomId) {
        return $http.get('api/Rooms/' + roomId).then(function (response) {
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                _room = response.data;
                return response.data;
            } else {
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            }
        }, function (response) {
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        });
    };
```